# Correct way to run jquery code depending on screen resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, screen

I have a multi-level mega menu on my site (using jquery plugin), however, when the site is being viewed on a mobile device, I want to run different JS code on the menu, in order to have a mobile friendly select menu. What is the correct way for me to check which code to run, something like if screen width less than 768px wide? Is there a standard way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the `window.screen` object.

```
if( screen.width < 768 ) {
    // do some js
}
```

Comment: jAndy - that's what I was thinking, but wasn't sure if this was the standard way of dealing with this. Thanks

Comment: here is no public standard that applies to the screen object, but all major browsers support it.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_screen.asp

Answer (score 0):

Hi as per the Question you can change the styles and code by using media attribute in your `link` tag

For detailed explaination refer the blog here..

[Create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website](http://www.instantshift.com/2010/12/20/how-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)

Comment: media queries will only effect stylesheets, not javascript.

Comment: i think you should create two version of your website and check the agent using javascript and redirect the user accordingly, rather than adding the script on regular web page.. user agents and do the work for you, to open the correct format of website, based on the device.